# Setting up a custom domain name in Nginx (Laravel 5.4) on EC2

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, dns, routes

I'm building a site builder where users have a subdomain `username.myapp.com` using wildcard subdomains to serve up their website (which works).

I want to allow users to use their own domain name so I setup `dns.myapp.com` which points to the server IP address.

In my domain name provider I've added `www.customdomain.com` CNAME to map to `dns.myapp.com`

It looks like `www.customdomain.com` is pointing to the server but it's not hitting the Laravel route and I get the Nginx 404 error page.

I've built a test method just to display the full domain path and check it's resolving;

RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Route::pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.\-]+');
    parent::boot();
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@domain');
});
```

Controllers/PageController.php

```
public function domain($domain)
{
    return $domain;
}
```

I can enter `anything.myapp.com` and it will return that path. I am trying to get `www.customdomain.com` to do the same.

This probably doesn't make a difference but `myapp.com` is in AWS Route 53 mapping to an EC2 server implemented through Laravel Forge.

EDIT: Nginx config:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/myapp.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name .myapp.com;
    root /home/forge/myapp.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/myapp.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/myapp.com/after/*;
```

Comment: try add "    server_name _" it fixed issue?

Comment: I'll try that now. So just add "server_name _" with a space after the second underscore?

Comment: I'm new to this. Do I need to add a colon ; at the end too?

Comment: Do you have any other `server` blocks in your configuration? The only way this `server` block would not process all domains, would be if you have another `server` block to act as the default server.

Comment: I don't think so. I've not added any as this is generated by default through Forge. I can check; where would they likely be?

Comment: I seem to only have 1 config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.com` which I have posted above.

Comment: @JackBarham, just add new line "server_name _;" after first server_name line. Also, this is not full config: you not included forge-conf/myapp.com/before/*; and usually in  /etc/nginx/ more config files.

Comment: Add output of `curl -v www.customdomain.com` and also check if `host www.customdomain.com` and `host myapp.com` returns the same ip

Comment: @turun they do return the same IP address so the domain is hitting the correct server.

Comment: @bukkojot there are no files in `forge-conf/myapp.com/before/` and I have added my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file above. There are no other .conf files in that directory.

Comment: Okay, add line "server_name ~.;" - this is kind of hack, but must work.

Comment: That's worked! Write it up as an answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you and setup multiple domains, you must config not only your DNS, but also your http servers to handle new domains.

If you have only one `server {}` directive, it acts as default server. Even if your users uses IP or any other alias. Such servers receive much junk traffic, so good practice is create "dummy page" as default server and real server will handle only good queries.

But sometime it's not working. You can do a hack:

```
server_name ~.;
```

It uses regular expression as "any string" and will work in anyway. Reasons, why don't work first server directive is unclear: possible somewhere included other config, patched nginx or even proxy at hoster side.